# Documenting custom Python functions in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, field-calculator, qgis-custom-function

How can I document my custom Python functions in QGIS?

I would like to offer users help for functions I wrote for them:

[image]

I've tried adding a docstring:

[image]

But whenever I click *Load* an error message is displayed:

[image]

The error message clearly shows an indentation error, which does not correspond to my actual code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are doing is the correct way to document your custom function.
The error you are encountering is because by default when you write a function in the *Function Editor*, the indentation before the `return` statement is that of 4 spaces characters and not 'tab space'. Just check if that is the case. The indentation should be consistent (either only spaces or tab space).

Comment: @ nash is right. I just tested the function and there's an error only when using a tab space instead of 4 spaces. +1, good answer!

Comment: Good thinking! This means that the error message is correct as well. It is strange that sometimes, but not always, when you hit Enter QGIS uses a tab instead of space characters, meaning that QGIS adds an error by default. Although I cannot figure out when exactly it doesn’t do it correctly.