# Documenting custom Python functions in QGIS using styles?

Tags: qgis, qgis-custom-function, documentation

[This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232976/documenting-custom-python-functions-in-qgis) shows how to document a custom function. However, I'd like to document my function in the same way the rest of the functions are.

[image]

So far, I just can manage to create the highlited part of the documentation but I can't find anywhere how to implement the same format used for the rest of the functions.

Is it possible to accomplish this in a custom function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use HTML and/or CSS in the function's DocString.

[image: viewing custom doc format]

[image: creating fancy documentation]

Comment: Great!! This is exactly what I was looking for. Do you know where can I find inside the QGIS files some of the preset functions so I can copy the same template?

Comment: @Albert I couldn't find them.. maybe they are in the source code, but there is no guarantee they are using the same mechanism/language

Comment: Oh, I couldn't find them either. Well, at least now I know how to do it manually. Thank you!

Comment: the scale_exp function appears to be [documented using json](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/8ac1460d0e760b288ca20e88529737c3b5cde137/resources/function_help/json/scale_exp), as @JGH suggests it's not necessarily a python function.